# Table Layout with WebView

Tags: android

I am adding `webview` in `table row` and loading data, but data is not displaying for me, can anybody tell what is problem. If it `linear layout` working but not working in `table layout` with table row?

****main.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <WebView android:id="@+id/link4_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SampleWebCheckActivity.java**

```
package com.samplecheck;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleWebCheckActivity extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.link4_view);
        String data="sample 1234 2345 5678 123456 ";
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

       // wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, mimeType, encoding, failUrl)(data, "text/html", "UTf-8");

    }
}
```

Even I used loadData it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're providing `null` for the first parameter of loadDataWithBaseURL which will defaults to 
`about:blank`.

Try this:

```
browser.loadData("<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8");
```

[WebView on Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) has a very nice explanation actually.

Answer (score 1):

When I have main.xml like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TableRow >
         <android.webkit.WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And code like this...

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/flashcard.html");
```

And an HTML file like this...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>temp</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black; color: white;">
  <p>
    <strong>Hello</strong> World!
  </p>
  <p>This is too cool</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It does exactly what the original poster describes.  I was required to not put the WebView inside of a TableLayout/TableRow combination before it would work consistently.  Further more, it was working, then not working, depending on the spaces or something in the HTML file.

To me, this looks very much like a bug.  Android development in general is very awkward and buggy.  You have to get things just right, or they simply don't work.  I love android overall, but the development sucks.

Comment: Whether it's a bug or a restriction of the layout markup I'm not yet sure, but from looking around after experiencing it myself apparently Table row gets its height from the element it contains. At launch a webview has height of 0, so even if your webview loads with the information you wanted it won't be visible